# Use javascript onclick in a while PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop

I am trying to plus or minus 1, a simple quantity input box, which can be different like in the picture below :

[image]

**PHP:**

```
$query = ...
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="id_part">
     <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>_count"><br>
     <input type="button" value="-" id="minus" onclick="minus()">
     <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
     var count = 1;
     var id = document.getElementById("id_part").value;
     var countEl = document.getElementById(id + "_count");
     function plus(){
      count++;
      countEl.value = count;
     }
     function minus(){
      if (count > 1) {
       count--;
       countEl.value = count;
      }  
     }
</script>
```

It doesn't work. It takes me only the first id quantity box. Can't manage to edit the second quantity box, where the id should be different. As you can see, I assigned each id tag with different names, taken from database id.

Comment: You're re-using `id` values, which is invalid in HTML.  Use unique `id` values.

Comment: Why not using input type number for this behavior ? [(doc, scroll to Input Type Number
)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) [(example)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number)

Comment: I don`t like the aspect of that input.

Comment: I would register the event for all the buttons in one single line: `$(document).on('click', 'button[id^=minus]', handler)` and it could use `closest` function in jquery to get the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/ja7ttx7k/)**.

That happen because you've a duplicate id's when the `id` attribute should be unique.

Please use common classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

The ID id_part is being generated for every row in your script. 
When you click on the button it finds the instance of id_part and its first value and edits its value.

Use unique ids say `id='id_part' +<?php echo $row['id']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually your Hidden field ID should be unique but it is in loop and returning the same value for all rows.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $q; ?>" id="**id_part**">

Try blow changes,
change your inner html as below
<input type="button" value="-" id="minus" onclick="minus(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">
<input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">


<script>
     var count = 1;
     function plus(position){
      count++;
      var countEl = document.getElementById(position + "_count");
      countEl.value = count;
     }
     function minus(position){
      if (count > 1) {
       count--;
       var countEl = document.getElementById(position + "_count");
       countEl.value = count;
      }  
     }
</script>
```

Comment: I got it working so far with this, except one detail. If I plus 1 in the first quantity box, and then I plus 1 in the second quantity box, the new value from the second box will be the the first value from first box + 1, not from the second at it should be.

Comment: Try it in a fiddle with static id and values, You will understand what am I saying.